# How to check if year changed in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My invoice number format is `[YYYY]-[4-digit Number]`. For example, `2014-0123`. I want to reset invoice number to `2015-0001` when the year changes (i.e, `[Next year]-[0001]`) from a stored procedure. How can I do that? Also I want this to happen every year.

This is the query I use to generate Invoice Number.

```
SELECT @INV_NO = SUBSTRING(CAST(SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '+05:30') AS VARCHAR),1,4) 
+ '-' + right('0000'+ ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(max),CONVERT(BIGINT,MAX(SUBSTRING(INV_NO,6,4)))+1),1),4) 
FROM dbo.IMG_TRN_INV
```

Now I don't know how to reset invoice number every year from stored procedure.

Comment: Do some research on GETDATE() and DATEPART, cook up some SQL and post it here and we may be able to help. You'll also need to describe what process creates your invoice numbers. Is it an application? You'll need to post the code then.

Comment: @Aniruddha Edit your question instead

Comment: I'd do a trigger BEFORE INSERT based on current date, I think.

Comment: USE YEAR(date) function.

Comment: Aniruddha, one thing is not clear here. An year starts means, it must be Jan 1st. You are using a query, it is not a table's auto increment column. There should be a reference for the sql, right?

Comment: It's no auto-increment column. I stored current year in a table and then compared it every time with year extracted from getdate() and now it's working the way i want.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Probably a silly question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that IMG_TRN_INV is the table that holds the invoice numbers (I used a temporary table: @IMG_TRN_INV):

```
-- temporary table setup
declare @IMG_TRN_INV table (id int identity(1, 1), INV_NO varchar(10))
insert into @IMG_TRN_INV(INV_NO) values ('2013-0018') -- use this to test new number for 2014
-- insert into @IMG_TRN_INV(INV_NO) values ('2014-0003') -- use this to test existing number for 2014

declare @INV_NO varchar(10)

if(exists(select * from @IMG_TRN_INV where patindex(cast(year(getdate()) as varchar(10)) + '-%', INV_NO) > 0))
    begin
        -- generate new invoice number from the last existing
        declare @LAST_INV_NO varchar(10) = (select top 1 INV_NO from @IMG_TRN_INV order by INV_NO desc)
        declare @NEW_NO int = cast(replace(@LAST_INV_NO, cast(year(getdate()) as varchar(10)) + '-', '') as int) + 1

        set @INV_NO = cast(year(getdate()) as varchar(10)) + '-' + replicate('0', 4 - len(@NEW_NO)) + cast(@NEW_NO as varchar(10))
    end 
else
    begin
        -- generate new invoice number for this year
        set @INV_NO = cast(year(getdate()) as varchar(10)) + '-0001'
    end

print @INV_NO
```

Comment: Thanks. I stored current year in a table and then compared it every time with year extracted from getdate(). I think it's working. Will try your solution as well.